# Jquery Long press and prevent click

Tags: jquery

One button, detecting click and long press:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  CLICK()
});

$('#button').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
    LongPressTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      LONGPRESS()
    }, 1000)
  })
  .on('mouseup mouseleave touchend', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    clearTimeout(LongPressTimer)
  });
```

Click works, long press works.
But a long press also invokes a click.

What needs to be changed so that a long press does not invoke a click?

Comment: `if (!longPressed) {CLICK()}`

Comment: Where is `e` defined? Where is `event` defined?

Comment: Question updated to define e.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a boolean to check if the event fired. I am using dataset to avoid all the extra global variables.

```js
const fncClick = () => console.log('click');
const fncLong = () => console.log('long');

$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!this.dataset.ignoreClick) {
    fncClick();
  }
});

$('#button').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
    const btn = this;
    delete this.dataset.ignoreClick;
    btn.dataset.longPressTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      fncLong();
      btn.dataset.ignoreClick = true;
    }, 1000)
  })
  .on('mouseup mouseleave touchend', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(this.dataset.longPressTimer)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">hm</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on the ideas from Justinas and Epascarello above.

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if(DidLP) {DidLP=false; return false}
CLICK()
});

$('#button').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
LongPressTimer = setTimeout(function() {
LONGPRESS();
DidLP=true;
}, 1000)
})
.on('mouseup mouseleave touchend', function(e) {
clearTimeout(LongPressTimer)
});
```

Comment: if you like globals... go ahead. You really should look at common naming standards with JavaScript.

Comment: Globals or not would be the answer to another question. My answer, based on your idea, is shorter, answers the question and might be better able to help others trying to find a solution for longPress.

Comment: SHORTER does not make things better. lol If you formatted your code it is not much different in length. :)

Comment: Epascarello, I had a look here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp and apparently, you can use any style as long as you are consistent throughout the code.

Comment: Feel free to not take my advice. If you get into the industry you are not going to use using Pascal Case for variable names at the company.

Comment: Espacarello, send me a link bro. Thanks.